# Error with Linq to Entities and user-defined aggregate function in EF 6 (code-first)

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I have a custom code-first aggregate function:

```
[DbFunction("CodeFirstDatabaseSchema", "Custom")]
public static int? Custom(this IEnumerable<ModelClass> g, Expression<Func<ModelClass, int>> field) {
    throw new NotSupportedException();
}
```

I then try to query using the custom function:

```
DbSet<ModelClass> models = ...;

var query = from a in models
                group a by a.ColumnName into newgroup
                select newgroup.Custom(g => g.ColumnName);

string sql = query.ToString();   // error "the linq expression node type 'lambda' is not supported in linq to entities."
```

At runtime, I then get the error "The linq expression node type 'lambda' is not supported in linq to entities." The strange thing is if I use "newGroup.Sum(g => g.ColumnName)", the query works as expected. The signature for Sum seems to be almost identical to my custom function so I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong

I can't post the exact code for ModelClass due to confidentiality, but it's just a basic entity class, i.e.:

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema

[Table("name")]
public class ModelClass {
   public long id {get; set;}
   public string field {get; set;}

   ...
}
```

Comment: Can you post the code of your ModelClass please ?

Comment: Is it a compiled error or an exception that is thrown ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14852122/why-lambda-is-not-supported-in-my-linq-to-entities-syntax

Comment: @Thomas: It is an exception that is thrown at runtime

Comment: @Ingweland: I've already looked at that post and while it is the same error, the solution there doesn't seem to help in my case